# Sqlite as OfflineDB

Tags: sqlite, jaydata

Which is the best option while working for offline DB?

- sqlite with jaydata
- sqlite
- sqlite with node.js

(Now I am working on Jaydata + Sqlite but I am enable to perform some functionality using JSQL example:multiple grouping)

Comment: Please be more specific! Describe the environment end the scenario!

Comment: @Robesz: I am developing an accounting software as chrome app for which I need a local storage while working offline.I have found Jaydata with sqlite a better option but some work can not be done when I am using Jaydata with sqlite.